# After Delete trigger, Function

Tags: postgresql, heroku-postgres

I have a trigger that looks like:

```
create trigger syncdataprodTrigger
after insert or update or delete on schema.table
for each row
execute procedure schema.schemaProdTableDataSync();
```

and a function that contains this snippet:

```
elseif (TG_OP = 'DELETE') then
delete from schema.table where id1 = old.id1;
RETURN NEW;
```

What I am expecting is that when a row is deleted from the first table it deletes it from the second table, but I am not getting this. What am I doing wrong and what can I be doing differently?

Comment: You need to post the whole function and the statement you run.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work, turns out that derps happen and the trigger needed to be changed to the right table...